# Bootstrap 3 display links and text inline within TD

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an odd issue, I cannot get the last row that contains 2 links and text to appear inline, instead it wraps.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3>Results</h3>
      <form action="/Search" class="form-inline" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
                <th>Col 5</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <a href="#" data-pageindex="3" class="pager">[Previous]</a> 
Page 5 of 30 
<a href="#" data-pageindex="5" class="pager">[Next]</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the text-nowrap class, and tried a number of CSS inline statements without any luck.

How do I get the last cell to have the text appear on the same line such as:

> [Previous] Page 5 of 30 [Next]

instead of:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the section in a form tag with the `form-inline` class, then wrap the previous and next anchor links in divs with the `form-group` class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
          <th>Col 5</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
                <a href="#" data-pageindex="3" class="pager">[Previous]</a>
              </div>
              Page 5 of 30
              <div class="form-group">
                <a href="#" data-pageindex="5" class="pager">[Next]</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, you could also remove the pager class from your anchor tags to get it to work normally.

Should you want actual Bootstrap styled pagers, you need to use them with an unordered list, like so:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped" border="1">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                    <th>Col 3</th>
                    <th>Col 4</th>
                    <th>Col 5</th>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                      <nav>
                        <ul class="pager pull-left">
                          <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                          Page X of Y
                          <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </nav>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Only slight downside is it makes the row they're in a bit wider.

Comment: That worked, but it seems like a lot to do to regain what is default behavior in HTML

Comment: Well that's what has to be done if you want to use the pager class on your anchor links. Alternatively, you could use them on an unsorted list so they not only look better, but will work with much less markup. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-pager I'll work that into my answer if you wish.

Comment: I need the class name name in the anchor tag because I have a bit of jQuery that posts the page when the link is clicked. That would be great if you could post an updated example.

Comment: I did it already. :D Unless there's soemthing else someone knows that I don't, you'll have to use my first example to get it inline because the Boostrap components can force it to act like one, which means it can make them inline. You can also reconsider how you're handling it and rewrite your jQuery, but that's on you to decide, I merely provided an answer to the problem you were having. :P